# Minimum sampling size for calculating mean in an experiment with serial measurements

Tags: time-series, t-test, mean, sample-size

**Background**: I am working in identifying best practices for conducting a specific mechanical test in materials. This mechanical test determines a material property and consists in performing consecutive measurements of such property in the same sample. In the end of the test, the results are a set of measurements (the example shown in the image below is for a test lasting 1025 seconds with 223 measurements/estimates) that naturally present a variance.

[image]

After a test, it is supposed that an estimator (mean, median, etc.) is used to produce a single value for the property for that sample. After seeing from Q-Q plots and histograms that, in general, a set of measurements in the same sample reasonably follows a normal distribution and that, in general, it does not present evident correlation, I decided to suggest using the mean as the estimator. Some times the first couple of measurements seem to be correlated, which is a sympton that the equipment is performing some kind of stabilization and I believe it is physically justified to disregard them when taking the mean value of the set.

**My question**:  Is it possible to define a minimum number of measurements to be made before taking the mean, so a given statistical metric is probably guaranteed (either a confidence level, a given variance, etc.)? In practical terms, I want to objectively suggest a number of measurements an operator may take in order to expect a given precision from the obtained mean.

**Attempts made so far**: I thought of using t-tests for comparing means, *e.g.*, in a test run with **(N)** measurements, I would compare the mean of the first **(*x*)** measurements with the mean of the rest **(N-*x*)** measurements. I would then progressively do that until not being able to reject null hypothesis, which should define the minimum set of measurements. But I am not sure if such approach is statistically sound. Also, I am not sure if this could handle the possibility that the first couple of measurements can be correlated and, thus, disregarded.

**Disclaimer**:  I would say I don't have a very advanced understanding of statistics: took some  theorectical courses, but have little practice.